# How to compute $P(X=1,Y=1,Z=-1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, which take only the values $-1$ and $+1$, and $P(X=1)=a$, $P(Y=1)=b$ and a third random variable $Z$ is defined by $Z=\cos((X+Y)\frac{\pi}{2})$. Can you explain how to compute $P(X=1,Y=1,Z=-1)$ ?

First I thought, to check if $X=1$ and $Y=1$, can $Z=-1$ be possible.

Then answer is yes, but how to compute now ?

Does $Z$ have no influence on the probability, either it is false(for example $P(X=1,Y=1,Z=2)$), then the probability is $0$ or if it's possible then we compute like;

$P(X=1,Y=1,Z=-1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)=ab$

but the result should be $0$, maybe a typo ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Z$ is fully determined by $X$ and $Y$, i.e. $Z=f(X,Y)$, and since $X,Y$ are independent $$
  P(X=x, Y=y, Z=z) = \begin{cases}
    P(X=x)P(Y=y) &\text{if $z=f(x,y)$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise,}
  \end{cases}
$$
as you say.

Our $f$ is $f(x,y) = \cos\left((x+y)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, so we have to check if for $x=1,y=1$ we have $$
  z = -1 \overset?= \cos(\pi) = f(x,y) \text{,}
$$
which we indeed do.

So yes, $$
  P(X=1,Y=1,Z=-1) = P(X=1)P(Y=1) = ab \text{.}
$$

Comment: this book have then a lot of typos, thank you very much.

Comment: @derivative Seems so ;-) My guess is that they meant to write $Z=1$ insteado $Z=-1$.